# batch file that copies a file to existing folder and renames it with current month and year

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need to write a batch file that copies a file to existing folder and renames it with current month and year.

At the moment, my batch file consists of only this command:

> @ECHO OFF
>   copy /y D:\SalesMixExp\Sales_Mix_v1.2_082015.xlsx D:\SalesMixExp\Sales_Mix_v1.2_092015.xlsx**

I am running this every month and it works fine. But every time I am changing the newly created filename with current month and year. i.e for ex: 092015 in my filename is **sep2015** and for next month it should be automatically renamed as **Sales_Mix_v1.2_102015**

Please help me in resolving my problem.  So that I don't have to change it every month.

Comment: So you want to copy the file with current `MMYYYY` in the name, to `MM+YYYY` automatically? Would you schedule this as a windows task for the 1st of the month or something?

Comment: Since there is SQL server tag, do you plan to use it as a scheduler by using Sql Server Integration Services? It is doable but way over the top for such simple function.

Comment: yes i scheduled it for 1st of the month

Comment: Why there is SQL server as one of the tags?

Comment: No Yasskier SSIS is not installed in client machine and wont allow me to do that because it is live. Actually the Sales_Mix is Excel pivot table. A sql view is attached to it and if refreshed it takes current month and year as condition and refresh the data. I need to create a copy every month and rename it with that month and year  automatically

Comment: Yasskier... client using **sql server 2008 R2** Iam importing data to excel pivot table from sql server query(View).

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the answer......

@echo off
set Date=%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
copy D:\SalesMixExp\Sales_Mix_v1.2_082015.xlsx D:\SalesMixExp\Sales_Mix_v1.2_%Date%.xlsx

But it works fine only when the file or folder names doesn't contain gaps.